# is counter has certain value inside a class in python

Tags: python, class

i am learning classes in python and when i was reading the documentation i found  this example that i didn't understand :

```
class MyClass:
    """A simple example class"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        i = 12345
    def f(self):
        return 'hello world'
```

then if we assign :

```
x = MyClass()
x.counter = 1
```

now if we implement while loop :

```
while x.counter < 10:
       x.counter = x.counter * 2
```

so the value of x.counter will be :

```
16
```

while for example if we have a variable y :

```
y = 1
while y < 1 :
   y = y *2
```

then if we look for the value of y we find it

```
1
```

so i don't know how is the value of counter became 16 .

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this doesn't really have anything to do with classes in particular, but here is what is happening...

```
x == 1 # x is less than 10, so it is doubled
x == 2 # x is less than 10, so it is doubled
x == 4 # x is less than 10, so it is doubled
x == 8 # x is less than 10, so it is doubled
x == 16 # now x is greater than 10, so it is not doubled again
```

Answer (score 1):

```
y = 1
while y < 1 :
   y = y *2
```

Always give same input, if you want same output.

You see that you are checking `y < 1` which would fail on first run. Make it `y < 10`, as you are having in your `x.counter` case.

```
y = 1
while y < 10:
   y = y *2
```